# Blender Startup script won't run when opening file

Tags: scripting

so I have this script that I placed on \2.82\scripts\startup folder in a Blender daily build.

- When I start Blender, the script does run, however, when I open a .blend file (outside of Blender, meaning Blender isn't running yet), the script doesn't run.
- When I start Blender, and open the file inside Blender, the script works.

I want the scripts to run everytime I open a file without having to run Blender first. I've already tried a different daily build but it still doesn't work.

I'm using Vaughan Ling's HeavyPoly scripts, and those seem to run just fine. I've checked some of the scripts, and I couldn't really figure out why his scripts works and mine doesn't.

This is my script btw.

```
    import bpy
    from bpy.types import Menu, Operator

    class ROJ_OT_setoffsetcursor(Operator):
        bl_label = "Set Offset"
        bl_idname = 'obj.setoffsetcursor'
        coll_name: bpy.props.StringProperty(name='Coll Name', default='')

        def execute(self, context):
            view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer
            view_layer.active_layer_collection = view_layer.layer_collection.children[self.coll_name]
            bpy.ops.object.instance_offset_from_cursor()
            print(self.coll_name)     
            return {'FINISHED'}


    class ROJ_MT_setoffsetmenu(Menu):
        bl_label = "Set Offset from Cursor"

        def draw(self, context):

            coll_list = []
            for coll in bpy.context.object.users_collection:
                coll_list.append(coll.name)

            layout = self.layout
            pie = layout.menu_pie()
            col = pie.split().column(align=True)
            col.operator('')

            pie = layout.menu_pie()
            col = pie.split().column(align=True)
            for coll in coll_list:
                row = col.row(align=True)
                row.scale_y=1.5
                prop = row.operator('obj.setoffsetcursor', text=coll)
                prop.coll_name = coll

    addon_keymaps = []

    def register():
        bpy.utils.register_class(ROJ_MT_setoffsetmenu)
        bpy.utils.register_class(ROJ_OT_setoffsetcursor)

        wm = bpy.context.window_manager
        kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
        km = kc.keymaps.new('Window', space_type='EMPTY', region_type='WINDOW', modal=False)
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new('wm.call_menu_pie', 'S', 'PRESS', alt=True, ctrl=True)
        kmi.properties.name = "ROJ_MT_setoffsetmenu"
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))


    def unregister():
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(ROJ_MT_setoffsetmenu)
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(ROJ_OT_setoffsetcursor)
        wm = bpy.context.window_manager
        kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
        if kc:
            for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
                km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
       addon_keymaps.clear()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        register()
```